# Attempt to invoke virtual method Error in android studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I develop android app and it was working fine I didn't change source code but today I got error while running app on emulator.

Here is the error in Android Studio:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean      java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                      at com.facebook.misstest.MessageAdapter.getView(MessageAdapter.java:36)
>                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
>                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
>                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:736)
>                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1665)
>                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
>                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)

and here is the code:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
  ChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
  if (chatMessage.getMessageUserId().equals(activity.getLoggedInUserName())) {
     view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_out_message, viewGroup, false);
  }  else {
     view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_in_message, viewGroup, false);
  }

  //generating view
  populateView(view, chatMessage, position);

  return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this is returning null

```
chatMessage.getMessageUserId()
```

so  null.equals() causing this exception

Comment: how to remove null?

Comment: just check for null value with if condition first , if it is null then skip your if else part

Comment: Thanks, i just fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

one of these `chatMessage.getMessageUserId()` or `activity.getLoggedInUserName()` is null, check before you use equals method

Comment: just before equals method, add another if and check whether your variables are null or not

Comment: Not working, can you please give me the example of the code?